# I am not understanding a phpunit function

Tags: php, phpunit

My PHPUnit test:

```
public function addWithNegative()
{
    $result = $this->calculator->add(-2, -2);
    $this->assertEquals(-5, $result);
}
```

My Code:

```
public function add($a, $b)
{
    return $a + $b;
}
```

The Problem I have (what i do not understand) is When i run my test, it still comes out as true/correct. Even thought the expected result should be -4.

Comment: put this function `assertEquals()` in above code

Comment: Have you checked that this test is running? It could be that your suite is passing but this test is not running for some reason. Could you put a `var_dump` in just to verify the result also? I know the answer should be -4 but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: What do you mean by, if the test is running ? This is the test output `PHPUnit 6.5.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.8
Configuration: /Users/user/Project/training/phpUnitTutorial/phpunit.xml

.........                                                           9 / 9 (100%)

Time: 48 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

OK (9 tests, 9 assertions)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test doesn't pass. It is not even executed because it is not a test.

By default, [only the public methods whose names start with `test`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) are treated by PHPUnit as tests.
An alternative way to tell PHPUnit that a method is a test is to use the [`@test` annotation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.test) in its docblock.

Accordingly, in order to make it a test you can change `function addWithNegative()` to either:

```
public function testAddWithNegative()
{
    $result = $this->calculator->add(-2, -2);
    $this->assertEquals(-5, $result);
}
```

or

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function addWithNegative()
{
    $result = $this->calculator->add(-2, -2);
    $this->assertEquals(-5, $result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i did not even notice.